# How to use subquery in views where clause

Tags: views, users

In my project user can created by [profile2 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2). When user is created i am assigning some role,initially user is block state. I have another user role ie.user app rover  who can approved these user and send activation link for active user.

I am using [Mail Logger](https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_logger) module for saving sending mail
Now i have created a view for user unapprove list

```
    SELECT users.name AS users_name, users.uid AS uid, users.mail AS users_mail, 
    profile_users.pid AS profile_users_pid, users.created AS users_created, 'profile2' AS 
    field_data_field_cc_first_name_profile2_entity_type, 'profile2' AS 
    field_data_field_cc_address_office_profile2_entity_type, 'profile2' AS 
    field_data_field_cc_designation_profile2_entity_type
         FROM 
         {users} users
         LEFT JOIN {profile} profile_users ON users.uid = profile_users.uid AND 
         profile_users.type IN ( 'company', 'goverment_profile' )
         WHERE (( (users.status = '0') AND (users.login = 0) AND (profile_users.type IN 
            ('company', 'goverment_profile')) ))
            ORDER BY users_created DESC
            LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Hear i want to add sub-query in where condition 
user those already send activation link who will not list in view.

My other table is mail_logger.

Is there any module by which i can use sub-query in where condition?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same question, here is what I found:

You can add a sub query to your view using the `hook_views_query_alter` hook in a custom module ([documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)). Inside the module you should add something like the following:

```
function your_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ( $view->current_display == '[display in question]'){
    $query->add_where_expression([group], [sub query]);
  }
}
```

[documentation for $query->add_where_expression](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3A%3Aadd_where_expression/7).  You can add whatever where clause you need using this function.

`hook_views_query_alter` should go in your_module.views.inc.  Make sure you declare `hook_views_api` in your_module.module, otherwise views wont know to look for the file. For example:

```
function your_module_views_api() { // declare your views api # here
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
  );
}
```